# Как синхронизировать получение кадров при изменении SeekBar?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, opencv, javacv

Это скорее больше как архитектурный вопрос.

Я разрабатываю приложение под Android, используя `FFmpegFrameGrabber` из пакета `JavaCV` для перебора кадров из видео. Задача стоит такая: при движении SeekBar - выставлять `bitmap` в `imageview`.

Хорошо, вот пример, который я максимально упростил:

```
seekHandBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
               if (b) {
                    try {
                        grabber.setFrameNumber(i);
                        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                converter.convert(grabber.grabImage()),
                                imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), true);
                        // converter здесь - это AndroidFrameConverter();
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    } catch (FFmpegFrameGrabber.Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

});
```

Проблема в том, что если использовать `grabImage()` в основном потоке при движении `seekbar` то происходит небольшая задержка, чего хочется избежать. Конечно, можно это вынести в метод `onStopTrackingTouch`, но я хочу попробовать разобраться изменять `Bitmap` именно при движении `seekbar`.

Было решено попробовать и `Thread`, и `ExecutorService` (пробовал `newCachedThreadPool` и `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`, может неправильно использовал для своей задачи) и `Runnable`, но это все не подходит, ибо нужна некая синхронизация (`queue`), когда следующий кадр будет обработан только после того, когда предыдущий был установлен. Все эти решения по сути просто создают новые потоки, которые выполняются произвольно, благодаря чему сначала может выставиться к примеру 30 кадр, а через некоторое время 25 кадр видео.

Что можно предпринять? Возможно нужно как-то использовать `synchronized`? Может я не туда копнул в поисках информации, или что-то упустил в `Executors`? Я только недавно столкнулся с задачами разделения на потоки в `java`, да и в целом по Android я новичок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея решения такая, что каждый раз когда получаем уведомление о `onProgressChanged` сохраняем номер кадра, который нужно прочитать. Перед началом запускаем фоновую задачу, которая ждет, когда появится этот номер кадра, и как только появился - она кадр считывает и использует.

Важный момент, что считывание кадров делается в одном потоке. Если во время считывания кадра пришло несколько номеров новых кадров, то нужно пропускать все кроме последнего, именно его считывать следующим.

Если говорить о реализации этой идеи, то тут возможны варианты. Пожалуй, самым простым будет использование очереди `LinkedBlockingQueue` для хранения номеров кадров, о которых нас известили.

```
ExecutorService grabberExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
BlockingQueue<Integer> grabQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
...
protected void onCreate(...) {

    seekHandBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                grabQueue.add(seekPos);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    });

    grabberExecutor.submit(this::grabberTask);
    ...
}

...
// метод, который выполняется в отдельном потоке и ждет задачи
// считывание кадров
public void grabberTask() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            int seekPos;
            seekPos = grabQueue.take();  // тут поток будет ждать пока не появится новый кадр
            while (!grabQueue.isEmpty()) {  // пропускаем все промежуточные номера кадров
                seekPos = grabQueue.take();
            }
            Bitmap bmp = grabImage(seekPos); // читаем последний полученный
            onFrameGrabbed(bmp);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log("grabber interrupted");
    }
}

Bitmap grabImage(int i) {
    try {
        grabber.setFrameNumber(i);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                converter.convert(grabber.grabImage()),
                imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), true);
        return bmp;
    } catch (FFmpegFrameGrabber.Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}

// взаимодействуем с UI в UI потоке
void onFrameGrabbed(Bitmap bitmap) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Доберусь сегодня до компьютера - ознакомлюсь с вашим ответом

Comment: Да, это то что нужно! Принимаю ваш ответ)